# Perfectly symmetrical curved line / edge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I'm trying to make the bottom edge of a layer curved / look like waves.

<s>Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve but it is just hand drawn:</s> (image no longer available)

As you can see, the curve is not symmetrical. What tool or method is guaranteed to get a perfect symmetrical, consistent curve along the edge?

Comment: Hello. Your image went down; do you think that you could replace it please? Stack Exchange has an image uploader; I'd advise using that.

Comment: @Mithrandir: Apologises, that image was uploaded 5 years ago, I don't have it anymore - but it it was essentially like the images you see in the answers except the curves were hand drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off with a layer with "solid box"

( It helps if all the sides you don't want to turn into wavey lines, are at the edges of the document. )

[image]

Then go do `Filter > Distort > Wave`

Important parts in the filter options:

- Number of generators: 1
- Type: Sine

You can go nuts with the other sliders.

[image]

End result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create this with adobe illustrator.
[image]